# PHP regex for checking if a string comes from single script whatever it was

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match-all

M3AAWG (Messaging, Malware and Mobile Anti-Abuse Working Group) delivered instructions for "Best Practices for Unicode Abuse Prevention":

- [M3AAWG Unicode Abuse Overview and Tutorial](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/default/files/m3aawg-unicode-tutorial-2016-02.pdf)
- [M3AAWG Best Practices for Unicode Abuse Prevention](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/default/files/m3aawg-unicode-best-practices-2016-02.pdf)

I want to implement this check: username field (PHP) meets this condition:

```
All characters in each identifier must be **from a single script** or from the combinations:
 - Latin + Han + Hiragana + Katakana
 - Latin + Han + Bopomofo
 - Latin + Han + Hangul
```

While the combinations part seems easy to code:

```
$nonLatinHanHiraganaKatakana = preg_match_all('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}\\p{Han}\\p{Hiragana}\\p{Katakana}]/u', $value);
$nonLatinHanBopomofo = preg_match_all('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}\\p{Han}\\p{Bopomofo}]/u', $value);
$nonLatinHanHangul = preg_match_all('/[^\\p{Common}\\p{Latin}\\p{Han}\\p{Hangul}]/u', $value);

// If none of the allowed combinations by M3AAWG, then reject
if ($nonLatinHanHiraganaKatakana && $nonLatinHanBopomofo && $nonLatinHanHangul)
{
    // REJECT
}
```

Are there an easy way to check if a string comes from a single script? (meaning only {latin}, {greek}, etc... whatever it was?

The trivial staff seems to be checking against each script individually, but there are hundreds, and didn't seem practical, nor performance valuable. Perhaps there is a way to get the 'script' given each character in 'username'? So checking if there is more than one?

Comment: All from Latin: `'~\A\p{Latin}+\z~u'`, all from hangul: `'~\A\p{Hangul}+\z~u'`, etc.

Comment: Too many different single scripts, so no practical staff match every one separately.

Comment: Why do you care if they are all the same language characters? And what would that tell you?

Comment: to prevent unicode abuse: https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/default/files/m3aawg-unicode-tutorial-2016-02.pdf

Comment: Do you have list of the POSIX classes you want to match?

Comment: This is a case when you need to reverse the blacklisting logic to whitelisting. Only match what you allow.

Comment: Unicode block https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

Comment: Is IntlChar::getBlockCode available only for PHP 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely they are not just a bunch of 
blow-hards. If they are the standard 
bearers, let them provide a **list** of 
allowed combinations that you or anybody
can use to construct a regex with. And, 
there is nothing wrong with making a 
single regex.

`^(?>[\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]+|[\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Bopomofo}]+|[\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Hangul}]+)$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?>
      [\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]+ 
   |  
      [\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Bopomofo}]+  
   |  
      [\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Hangul}]+  

   # Add as many as you need
   # | \p{..}  
 )
 $
```

Comment: It will work to construct such a list with all the blocks here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block) in a reasonable performance way?

Comment: @framontb - Construction, performance is not an issue. Really, it's simple cut'n paste. We are talking _very simple math_ here in character classes. Ranges are a primitive assembly `>=low && <=high`. That's the actual engine math done when matching character classes. Compiling a single class with bunches of ranges always resolves to include sub-ranges. Example: `U+0000-U+007F,U+0080-U+00FF,U+0100-U+017F,U+0180-U+024F` resolves to  `[\u0000-\u024f]` or `\p{Latin}`. Just because it _looks_ big doesn't mean the result is big.

Comment: And a single `[\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]` class covers the individual blocks in case that's all you have. So, yeah, make a huge regex, put the most common ones at the top. But if you don't try it, you'll never know. In other words, **There isn't a faster way**. No magic on earth can beat primitive math that a regex engine uses. However, the engine is designed for string navigation as well. The combination is better than anything you or anybody else could do in a code kludge.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there an easy way to check if a string comes from a single script?
>   (meaning only {latin}, {greek}, etc... whatever it was?

Use a `switch` for "every" possible option, i.e.:

```
<?php
echo detectChars("例例")."\n";
echo detectChars("Χαίρετε")."\n";
echo detectChars("user345")."\n";

function detectChars($username){
$chars = "NOT ALLOWED";
switch(true){
case preg_match('/^\p{Common}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Common}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Arabic}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Arabic}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Armenian}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Armenian}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Bengali}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Bengali}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Bopomofo}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Bopomofo}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Braille}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Braille}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Buhid}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Buhid}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Canadian_Aboriginal}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Canadian_Aboriginal}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Cherokee}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Cherokee}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Cyrillic}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Cyrillic}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Devanagari}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Devanagari}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Ethiopic}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Ethiopic}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Georgian}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Georgian}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Greek}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Greek}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Gujarati}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Gujarati}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Gurmukhi}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Gurmukhi}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Han}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Han}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Hangul}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Hangul}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Hanunoo}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Hanunoo}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Hebrew}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Hebrew}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Hiragana}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Hiragana}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Inherited}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Inherited}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Kannada}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Kannada}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Katakana}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Katakana}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Khmer}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Khmer}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Lao}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Lao}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Latin}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Latin}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Limbu}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Limbu}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Malayalam}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Malayalam}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Mongolian}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Mongolian}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Myanmar}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Myanmar}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Ogham}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Ogham}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Oriya}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Oriya}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Runic}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Runic}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Sinhala}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Sinhala}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Syriac}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Syriac}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Tagalog}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Tagalog}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Tagbanwa}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Tagbanwa}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Tamil}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Tamil}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Telugu}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Telugu}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Thaana}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Thaana}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Thai}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Thai}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Tibetan}+$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Tibetan}");
    break;
case preg_match('/^\p{Yi} +$/u', $username):
    $chars = preg_replace('/\\\\p|\{|\}/m', '', "\p{Yi}");
    break;
}
return $chars;
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
Han
Greek
NOT ALLOWED
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/CCLmlO)

Comment: Why don't you make a script to create the `switch` for you based on a list of POSIX classes ?

Comment: The `switch` maximizes the performance but, as far as I know, there's no easy solution for your problem.

Comment: IntlChar::getBlockCode() gets the Unicode allocation block containing a code point. I could check each character in username buffering the block name in an array and do an array_unique... if only one, then is done !!!... but I don't know if there is IntlChar::getBlockCode() outside PHP 7 :-(

Comment: "***but I don't know if there is IntlChar::getBlockCode() outside PHP 7***" No, there isn't :(

Comment: brilliant: `preg_match('/\p{Hangul}+/u', $line_of_text)` - thx